# How to create drop-down in React-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to add a dropdown in my view.
I am new to rnative please help.

I also added a comment where I am trying to add a dropdown. I tried this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dropdown-picker but it Just giving me some error.

import React, {  useState } from 'react'; //import useState
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput,StatusBar, SafeAreaView,Image,Button,Alert} from 'react-native';

```
    export default function App() {
    
        const [search, setSearch] = useState(''); //add this line
        
      return (      
        
        <SafeAreaView>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput 
              onChangeText={(text) => setSearch(text)}
              
              placeholder="Search"
              style={styles.searchbox}                        
            ></TextInput>   
    
          <View style={styles.makecentral} >   
            {search.length < 1 ? <Image               
                style={styles.tinyLogo}
                source={require('./assets/icons8_search_200px_3.png')}        
              /> : ( 
                  null  //add clear text image and clear search text
                  
              )}
          
          </View>
                <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
    
                  <View elevation={2}  style={{flex:3,backgroundColor:'#ffffff',height:40,marginTop:10,marginLeft:'2.5%',borderBottomLeftRadius:5,borderTopLeftRadius:5}}>
                    <Text style={{textAlign:'center',fontSize:20,color:'#FF7B00',marginTop:7}}>
                      Category
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  
                  <View elevation={2} style={{backgroundColor:'#FF7B00',height:40,flex:5,marginTop:10,borderTopRightRadius:5,borderBottomRightRadius:5,marginRight:'2.5%'}}>

                   //here..I want to add a dropdown..
       
                  </View>
    
                
                </View>
    
        </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    }
    
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {    
        backgroundColor: '#fff',    
        
      },
    
      searchbox:{
        backgroundColor:'#f2f2f2',
        marginTop : StatusBar.currentHeight+5,
        height : 50,
        marginLeft:10,
        marginRight : 10,
        borderRadius : 20,
        textAlignVertical:'center',
        textAlign : 'center',
        alignItems:'center',        
      },
    
      tinyLogo: {
        position : 'absolute',
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        opacity: 0.5,
        marginTop: -40,    
      },
    
      makecentral: {
        alignItems:'center',
        marginRight:80,    
      },
    
      category:{
        backgroundColor:'#f2f2f2',
        height:50,
        width:'90%',
        alignContent:'center',
    
    
      }
    });
```

Comment: what is the error that it's giving you?

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsrHS57YPlM33SyN89lxvxI0nXMX?e=gVPSOn

Comment: When I try to add <DropDownPicker></DropDownPicker> in view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great npm package for adding drop-down : [react-native-dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dropdown-picker)

You can also use other components Library like [Ui Kitten](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/). Which contains a much better Drop-down.

This is a specific link to drop-down:- [Link](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/select/overview#select)

There are many other libraries you can use. Consider This:- [top libraries](https://www.codeinwp.com/blog/react-native-component-libraries/)

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your answer that you are not providing `items` to your `DropDownPicker`, therefore it crashes. You can't just give an empty component.

As per docs, it should look something like:

```
<DropDownPicker
    items={[
        {label: 'USA', value: 'usa', icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" />, hidden: true},
        {label: 'UK', value: 'uk', icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" />},
        {label: 'France', value: 'france', icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" />},
    ]}
    defaultValue={this.state.country}
    containerStyle={{height: 40}}
    style={{backgroundColor: '#fafafa'}}
    onChangeItem={item => this.setState({
        country: item.value
    })}
/>
```

`items` are actually the only prop which is required.

Please refer [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dropdown-picker)

Comment: where to pu this this.state = {
    country: 'uk'
}

Comment: nono, that was just an example - adapt it to your data. Add the data you want to show in your dropdown picker.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the library that you can use for create a dropdown picker in react native :-

[react-native-dropdown-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dropdown-picker)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dropdown-picker

Works very well since the native iOS picker changed to new version which isn’t very attractive or user friendly.

Make sure to read the doco about zindex and overlapping when using both platforms as this can cause some issues.